# How to explore all the properties of "this" in Composer Trace events?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'd like to be able to explore properties starting from the "this" pointer in Composer but I can't figure out the syntax to walk it in a Trace event.  I'd like walk all the way to turn.recognized.entities and then into it's properties. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question... Not sure why I was struggling with this one... Here is how to dump the entities ${turn.recognized.entities}